# ResourceNotFound on layout inflation

Tags: android

My app may launch a sub-activity for a specific purpose. When that activity finishes, I get the results in onActivityResult. These results are then processed in the subsequent onResume. This consists of a setContentView and also starting an AsyncTask that puts up a ProgressDialog.

This all works well when initiated the normal way, which is via a user request (i.e., menu selection) after the app is up and running. However, under some conditions I need to do this right as the app is starting up, so I initiate this sequence right from my onCreate. What then happens is that I get fatal ResourceNotFound errors within any o/s call that implicitly calls the layout inflater. I got around this with setContentView by pre-inflating the view in my onCreate method, but the AsyncTask's onPreExecute still fails on ProgressDialog.show() as it "fails to find" Android's own progress_dialog.xml!

Anyone know what's happening here?

I suspect it's something to do with the timing, where this is occurring before the main activity has even had a chance to display its screen. These calls are all being made on the main UI thread, but maybe something hasn't completed within the o/s under these conditions.

Comment: Post some code, we don't need a description of your code.

Comment: Please also include the full stacktrace of the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a closeout, the problem turned out to be totally unrelated to what I described in my post. Turns out it was due to blindly using some code that had been posted in some online forum showing how to get and use AssetManager. Trouble is, at the end of the block of code he had put "assMan.close()". Well, this closes the asset manager for the entire activity and resources can no longer be accessed!

It took a while to find it since it was not something that I did via my own understanding.