# Resource Not found exception on setContentView

Tags: android, view, resources

Good day.First i will say that no methods found from google helped me so i came here!Frustrating issue but here is what happening.I have simple layout folder with simples layout files.The app goes good on couple of screens and on the HomeActivity screen it is crashing giving this issue.It is important to mention that i have tested it on 2 different devices.On first device it all working fine,on second it is not.Both devices are on portrait mode and both have same screen size.I dont know what android studio is asking me to do,but the app was just working fine i did not do anything and sudennly android studio decides to give me this exception.So here is my code of the actual view crashing.

the xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_home"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_home"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_home_drawer" />
```

the xml file of `<include>`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_home" />


<android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionMenu
    android:id="@+id/fab"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom|right"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:src="@drawable/fab_add"
    app:layout_behavior="ink.utils.ScrollAwareFABBehavior"
    fab:menu_colorNormal="@color/colorPrimary"
    fab:menu_colorPressed="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    fab:menu_colorRipple="#cccccc">

    <fab.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/messages"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_message_white_24dp"
        fab:fab_colorNormal="#444f65"
        fab:fab_colorPressed="#636e85"
        fab:fab_label="@string/messageText"
        fab:fab_size="mini" />

    <fab.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/makePost"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_create_white_24dp"
        fab:fab_colorNormal="#444f65"
        fab:fab_colorPressed="#636e85"
        fab:fab_label="@string/makePostString"
        fab:fab_size="mini" />
</android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionMenu>
```

The activity where at `setContentView` i get the actual crash

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity
    implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener, View.OnClickListener {

private FloatingActionMenu mFab;
private ImageView mProfileImage;
private SharedHelper mSharedHelper;
private FloatingActionButton mMessages;
private FloatingActionButton mNewPost;
private Feed mFeed;
private MyFriends mMyFriends;
private Toolbar mToolbar;
private DrawerLayout mDrawer;
public static String PROFILE;
public static String FEED;
public static String MESSAGES;
public static String GROUPS;
public static String FRIENDS;
public static String SETTINGS;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
```

Beside googling and trying every possible solution checking for layout extra folders which i surely do not have,i only have one single layout folder,i have tried cleaning project,rebuilding,invalidating caches and restarting but nothing helped me at all...
here is the gradle dependency for the xml file

```
 compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:23.4.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.4.0'
```

Nothing extraordinary please can you help me and tell me what to do with this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ResourceNotFound on layout inflation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3991770/resourcenotfound-on-layout-inflation)

Answer (score 0):

There is also one more 'include' -layout content_home

Answer (score 0):

Got that fixed which was the far weird that someone could get.Anyway i found the drawables files of the project.Issue was at the part when i refactored an variable with key `name` i dont know why android studio decided to rename all my project  key`s within name to my input one.So there were no compiler issues nothing at all (which is far weird even) and all was working fine on one phone,and not on the other.So i removed that issue renamed to the default 'name' key and all got working.Be carefull as there are lot`s of weird things for now.